# Is temporary object initialization expresssion implicitly converted to xvalue while we access the this pointer?

Tags: c++, rvalue, xvalue, value-categories

The code is:

```cpp
class A {
public:
  void f() { cout << this; }
};

int main() {
  A{};     // prvalue
  A{}.f(); // Is A{} in here converted to xvalue?
}
```

On https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion, I learned the
Temporary materialization rules.
It tells an example:

```cpp
struct S { int m; };
int i = S().m; // member access expects glvalue as of C++17;
               // S() prvalue is converted to xvalue
```

This example applies this rule: when performing a member access on a class prvalue;

However, I'm not sure if accessing the this pointer is a special case of accessing a member.

Are there any other conversion rules that can help us determine if a prvalue to xvalue conversion is happening here

Comment: *"`A{}.f();` // Is A{} in here converted to xvalue?"* Yes. Why do you think it is different from `S().m`? Just because you're using `this` inside `f`?

Comment: As both `A{}` and `S()` are class prvalues and you're accessing the member `f` by writing `A{}.f()`, according to the above quoted statement, temporary materialization occurs and `A{}` prvalue is converted to xvalue.

Answer (score 1):

> `A{}.f();` // Is `A{}` in here converted to xvalue?

Yes, as both `A{}` and `S()` are class prvalues and you're accessing the member `f` by writing `A{}.f()`, according to the below quoted statement, temporary materialization occurs and `A{}` prvalue is converted to xvalue.

In particular, from [temporary materialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion):

> Temporary materialization occurs in the following situations:
>
> - when performing a member access on a **class prvalue**;

(emphasis mine)